# Cosine similarity--one to many

Tags: cosine-similarity

I'm wondering if there's any good way to use cosine similarity to compare a single document with a set of documents. Obviously you could calculate the cosine similarity between the single document and every document in the set, but if you did this would you then take the average? Would you weight by the size of each of the other documents you're comparing the original document with? I'm also wondering if there's any way to combine all of the word counts in the set of documents you're comparing with so that in the end you only compute cosine similarity once; between the original document and the "aggregated" document. The reason I'm asking is that I have about 200,000 documents that I want to compare with a separate set of about 50,000 documents.Comparing each of the 200,000 with each of the 50,000 is a lot of calculating and I don't know if it's actually necessary if I'm just going to take some sort of average in the end anyway. Is my aggregated document idea a big no-no?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to speed this up significantly. The point is to notice that the word vectors are sparse. Thus you want to transform your documents into a table which is organized by word columns. One column per word. For each column you only store the non zero entries. That is one row per document that actually contains the word. Then you compute the partial sums by going through the columns and collect the results per document. This has the additional advantage that it is easy to parallelize.

To speed this up further you create a column per word per set and only compute and distribute the partial sums for the same word for documents of different sets.